# Highlight initial SwiftUI List item when a Mac app launches

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a Mac app that uses a List to determine which view is displayed in the DetailView. UserDefaults saves the state of which view is displayed when the app launches.

However, the List item associated with the initial detail view is not highlighted when the app launches. How can I highlight the appropriate List item when the Mac app launches?

```
struct SidebarView: View {

    @State private var selected = Set([UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Selected") as? String ?? "Second View"])

    private let items = ["First View", "Second View", "Third View"]

    var body: some View {
        List(items, id: \.self, selection: $selected) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(selection: item)) {
                Text("\(item)")
            }
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {

    var selection: String

    var body: some View {
        switch selection {
        case "First View":
            UserDefaults.standard.set("First View", forKey: "Selected")
            return AnyView(FirstView())
        case "Second View":
            UserDefaults.standard.set("Second View", forKey: "Selected")
            return AnyView(SecondView())
        case "Third View":
            UserDefaults.standard.set("Third View", forKey: "Selected")
            return AnyView(ThirdView())
        default:
            return AnyView(
                Text("Some \(selection) view here").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    private let selected = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Selected") as? String ?? "Second View"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SidebarView()
            DetailView(selection: selected)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Actually it is there. If you click in the sidebar area (or hide-activate app) after app launch, you see that correct list item is highlighted. This looks like a Apple bug - incorrect initial first responder or key-view navigation.

Comment: @Asperi You're right. If I run my example app, then click somewhere outside the app and then click the example app again it makes the highlight appear on the appropriate item. Looks like the new Feedback Assistant is how to file bug reports to Apple https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/.